# Own array-implementation in Python

Tags: python

I was able to create my own class in C++ which is basically an array of fixed size, where I can append, retrieve, and change integers in.

This is the C++-code:

```
#include <iostream>


class List {
    public:
    //Item-object needed to store
    //elements
    struct Item {
        int data = 0;
        Item* next = nullptr;
    };

    //Constructor
    //creates a list of fixed size
    List(int size) {
        //Filling up with empty items
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Item* item = new Item;

            //If first item,
            //store start-address
            //set buffer to start address
            if (i == 0) 
                this->start = item;

            //Setting current item as nextptr
            //for previous item in buffer 
            if (i > 0)
                this->buffer->next = item;

            //Storing current address in buffer
            this->buffer = item;

            //Outputting address and value (just for testing purposes)
            //std::cout << "Address: " << &item << " -> " << item->data << std::endl;
        }
    }

    //Destructor
    ~List() {
        Item* current = this->start;
        while(current) {
            delete current;
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

    //Returns address of very first element in list
    Item* getFirstItemAddress() {
        return this->start;
    }

    //Append to list
    bool append(int value) {
        Item* start = this->start;

        //Calculating insertIndex
        int insertIndex = this->index *2;

        //Inserting
        (start + insertIndex)->data = value;

        //Increment index for next call
        this->index++;

        return true;
    }

    //Retrieve item at index from list
    int retrieve(int i) {
        //Error check (index out of range)
        if (i >= this->index) {
            std::cerr << "Index out of range!" << std::endl;
            throw("Index out of range");
            return -1;
        }

        i = i * 2;

        return (start + i)->data;
    }

    //Remove element at index from list
    bool remove(int index) {
        index = index * 2;

        //Shifting all elements above 'index'
        //one down
        Item* current = (this->start + index);
        while (current->next) {
            Item* next = current->next;
            current->data = next->data;
            current = next;
        }

        //Decrementing index
        this->index--;

        return true;
    }

    //Change element to value at index
    bool change(int index, int value) {
        index = index * 2;
        (this->start + index)->data = value;

        return true;
    }

    //Printing out list
    void print() {
        int counter = 0;

        Item* current = this->getFirstItemAddress();
        while (current) {
            if (counter >= this->index) break;

            std::cout << current->data << std::endl;
            current = current->next;

            counter++;
        }
    }

    private:
    //Holding address of first item
    Item* start = nullptr;

    //Buffer holding temporary address
    Item* buffer = nullptr;

    //Variable pointing to indexToInsert
    int index = 0;
};

int main() {
    List list(5);

    //Printing out
    /*std::cout << std::endl << "Testing output:" << std::endl;
    List::Item* current = list.getFirstItemAddress();
    while (current) {
        std::cout << current->data << std::endl;
        current = current->next;
    }*/

    List::Item* start = list.getFirstItemAddress();
    list.append(1);
    list.append(2);
    list.append(3);
    list.append(4);
    list.append(5);

    std::cout << list.retrieve(0) << std::endl;
    std::cout << list.retrieve(1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << list.retrieve(2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << list.retrieve(3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << list.retrieve(4) << std::endl;

    list.remove(2);

    std::cout << std::endl;
    list.print();

    std::cout << std::endl;
    list.change(3, 8);
    std::cout << list.retrieve(3) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But I actually want it in Python 3,
Python Code:

```
class Item:
    data = None
    next = None

    def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next



class List:
    start = Item()
    buffer = Item()
    index = 0

    def __init__(self, size):
        for i in range(0, size):
            item = Item

            if (i == 0):
                start = item

            if (i > 0):
                self.buffer.next = item

            buffer = item

    def getFirstItemAddress(self):
        return self.start

    def append(self, value):
        start = self.start
        insertIndex = self.index * 2
        (addressof(start) + insertIndex).data = value

        self.index+=1
        return True

    def retrieve(self, i):
        if i >= self.index:
            print("Index out of range")
            return -1
            exit()

        i = i * 2
        return (self.start + i).data

    def remove(self, index):
        index = index * 2

        current = (self.start + index)
        while current.next:
            next = current.next
            current.data = next.data
            current = next

        self.index-=1
        return True

    def print(self):
        counter = 0

        current = self.getFirstItemAddress()
        while current:
            if counter >= self.index: break

            print(current.data)
            current = current.next

            counter+=1

list = List(5)
list.append(1)
```

That code ain't working a little bit. I get errors like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 73, in <module>
    list.append(1)
  File "main.py", line 34, in append
    (start + insertIndex).data = value
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Item' and 'int'
```

Which is pretty logic, however, I need to be able to use SOME KIND of pointers and references in Python. Because I have to calculate index'es based on start-addresses etc.

I have researched a bit and stumbled on functions like 'id()', and 'addressof()' but those weren't working.

Without using special implementations like PyPy or CPython, how would I achieve this? I knew that in Python you have very little options to do memory management, but it's said that everything done in C++ can be done in Python... So how would I create my own made array-list implementation in Python?

**TL;DR**
I have created my own 'array-implementation' in C++, but I want it in Python3. However Python has very little memory management options like 'new', pointers, references,... I'm still searching for a way to achieve this in Python.

Comment: Python is a garbage-collected language. You need to understand this model before you attempt to do much anything at all related to memory management.

Comment: The error means that you should not use "+" between two classes. You could use "+" between two int variables.

Comment: @LNT I tried for example  (id(start) + insertIndex).data = value; but than got the error "Type integer doesn't have a member called 'data'" So how would I get the object at a specific address (int)

Comment: “start” is an Item object, which has "data" property. "id(start)" returns an address of "start", and the address is int object. Then you added them (id(start) + insertIndex). It's still an int object, which has no member called "data".